# C# code showing error "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, namespaces

I don't know why this error pops up I don't have anything declared out of class my full code is this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.IO;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Text;

namespace test
  {
  public class comp
   {
    static void Main()
    {
        string code="0x4d,0x41,0x2......"; //and soo onnn
        string Arch = " /platform:x86 /optimize";
        string filePath = "C:/menmon.exe";
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

        parameters.OutputAssembly = filePath;
        parameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:exe" + Arch;
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
          {
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
          }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Compiled this using cmd on Windows machine on .Net framework64 v4.0.30319
error happens after compilation(on compilation no error is shown) when I run the program this error pops up:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Error (CS0116):
>   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>
> at comp.Main()

I ran csc.exe like this

> csc /t:exe /out:"C:\output.exe" "C:\input.cs"

Comment: You have `using Microsoft.CSharp;` inside your `Main` method (line `string filePath = [...]`). Move it up to the other usings.

Comment: The error is clear.  It is saying you defined a member (either field or property or methods) directly under the namespace.  It should be under the class and not directly under namespace.

Comment: @diiN__________ That will not throw stated above exception.

Comment: what should I add or delete from this

Comment: Well, this is a compiler error, so in the Error List window you can double click on the error line and see the exact point where the error has been identified by the compiler.

Comment: I compiled it on CMD

Comment: This happens after compilation when I run the program,Sorry i forgot to add that

Comment: Your code is not compilable. You are missing a semicolon after your last line `CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code)`. Once this is fixed, try to add a namespace like `namespace myNamespace { ...}`

Comment: If you are able to compile that code without errors then perhaps the problem is in the _code_ variable. Something invalid there?

Comment: updated the code to add throw

Comment: The variable does not have any problem, It is a long byte array, Is there any way to compile byte array other than this?

Comment: The call to _CompileAssemblyFromSource_ throws the error so, your _code_ is not valid to be compiled in a standalone executable. There is a lot more to do than what you have now. See the example on Microsoft Docs if you want to use this path. For example  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure will this help you but can you please try to add namespace of your App just up of the class so it looks like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Also you are missing semi colon on the last line in main function.

Comment: Still same result

Comment: With new version of code sb.ToString() is not good at throw because its not declared in that scope.

Comment: Is there any way to compile byte array other than this? and what edit should i make

Comment: why did you close the question , my problem isn't solved